# Function of a point rotating around a moving center

Tags: trigonometry, linear-transformations

I am currently looking into the following issue:

Imagine a point $p$ rotating around a center (0,0). The equations for the coordinates as a function of time are:

$x = p_x  \cos(t) - p_y  \sin(t)$

$y = p_x  \sin(t) + p_y  \cos(t)$

with $ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 = p_x^2+p_y^2$

The center is not fixed but now also moving in x-direction which changes the equation for the x-coordinate to:

$x = p_x  \cos(t) - p_y  \sin(t) + c \cdot t$ with some constant $c$.

Now I am trying to find a corresponding function of $x$ for this.

The reason behind this is, that I try to find the exact coordinates (or the time $t$) of the intersection of this moving point with a line segment. As far as I understand, this is not possible, if I do not eliminate the (co-)sine-functions from the equations. After some research, I begin to wonder if this problem is solvable without approximations at all.

Comments?

Comment: Your first equatios seems weird to me! What I just don't understand is your first two equations! We have $x$ or $y$ at the both sides of the equation!

Comment: p is the point, which is rotated around the center with p.x being the x- and p.y the y-coordinate of this point. The results of the two equations are the x- and y-coordinates _after_ rotation around the center.

Comment: Ooops! To me and every body, $p.x$ means p multiplied by $x$! Do you mean that $p$ is a function of $x$, i.e., $p(x)$? or just $p_x$ is a constant?

Comment: No, p is a 2-dimensional point (x/y). p.x is the x-coordinate, p.y is the y-coordinate. The syntax resembles access to a member of a structure or object in common programming languages. What would be better? Just px and py, leaving out the dot?

Comment: Use just $p_x$ and $p_y$. :) This is a mathematics site not a programming one so should use notations which are common in mathematics.:)

Comment: and what do you mean by $0/0$?

Comment: The origin of a cartesian coordinate system

Comment: I read your question again and don't really understand the first part of it. I think that you have not properly stated your question. Good Luck. :)

Comment: small changes done; A similar situation occurs for a cycloid. Do you want to find function for $y$ also?